# What is logic of manipulation with timezones in Java/Kotlin?

Tags: java, kotlin, time, utc, timezone-offset

Let's assume that I have client's time saved in my database as `2020-09-22T10:50:37.276240900`

I need to present this date in web-service for client app depending on client timezone, for example I need to add 2 hours to saved date if client lives in UTC+2 timezone.

So what am I doing for ?

Getting date from entity and adding timezone to time taken from database (`startDate: LocalDateTime`)

```
entity.startDate.atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/Vienna"))
```

what gives me the value of `ZonedDateTime` `2020-09-22T10:50:37.276240900+02:00[Europe/Vienna]`

This value is what I'm expecting for, basically "initial time plus  2 hours". After that I would to format this time to have output with this 2 hours of being added, some kind of this

`12:50 22.09.2020`

but when I do format like this

```
entity.startDate
 .atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/Vienna"))
 .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(NotificationListener.EUROPEAN_DATE_FORMAT, Locale.ENGLISH))
```

where `const val EUROPEAN_DATE_FORMAT = "HH:mm dd.MM.yyyy"`

I get this output `10:50 22.09.2020`  which looks like my format is not applied properly, so I cannot see my 2 hours.

So my questions are:

1. am I correct to adding timezone of client app in described way ?
2. how to apply timezone in more precise way and format this date to see timezone zone applied ?

Comment: What type is `entity.startDate`?

Comment: "Let's assume that I have client's time save din my database as 2020-09-22T10:50:37.276240900" - and is that meant to be in UTC? What type are you using in Java or Kotlin to represent that? A [mcve] would make it much easier to help you.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that a date and time *without time zone information* does NOT uniquely identify a specific point in time. You *need* to use some timezone information (even if it's the "default" UTC) to convert that into a timestamp that has physical meaning. In other words: `LocalDateTime` is **not** a specific point in time, but `ZonedDateTime` is!

Comment: What are the contents of `EUROPEAN_DATE_FORMAT`?

Comment: Stepping back a moment here, the underlying issue is that you know something the database doesn't: you know that the dates it stores are in UTC.  (The question doesn't state that, but seems to assume it.)  Because the DB doesn't know that, it gives you a LocalDateTime, which has _no_ zone.  In order to do the conversion, you need to tell it that that is UTC before you can convert it to some other zone (e.g. converting to a ZonedDateTime, as per Joachin's answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LocalDateTime.atZone`  does not "move" the point in time. In fact it tries to present the point in time where the *local* time in the given timezone is exactly what the `LocalDateTime` shows.

In other words: if your `LocalDateTime` represented 10:00 at some date, then the `ZonedDateTime` output of `atZone` will also represent 10:00 *local time* at the specified time zone (except in cases where that local time doesn't exist due to DST changes).

So if your stored time is actually in UTC, you need to add one more step:

```
ZonedDateTime utcTime = entity.startDate.atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC);
ZonedDateTime localTime = utcTime.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("Europe/Vienna"));
```

Alternatively you can avoid calculating the localTime each time and instead configure the `DateTimeFormatter` to use a given time zone (which means it'll do the necessary calculations internally) [using `DateTimeFormatter.withZone`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#withZone(java.time.ZoneId)). If you do this then you can pass the `utcTime` to it directly.

Comment: Thank you for great explanation.
Is this approach applicable for summer/winter time changes ?

Comment: One thing that's outside the strict Java library scope is that your DB mapping layer might be able to do the `atZone` step if you tell it that the time in the DB is always stored in UTC. That way you can have your entity hold a `ZonedDateTime` and avoid a potential source of mistakes.